# Match 2 text in karatedsl with some part of the text can be random

Tags: karate

I have a question about matching 2 text where some part of the text can be random, for example there are two text below : 
Text 1 :

```
056722008232004108e1006000000000000001000524__144000478165532374__201905
```

Text 2 :

```
056722008232004108e1006000000000000001000524__184917547749997761__201905
```

Almost all of the text is the same excpet the text between underscore, what i want to do is match 2 texts above with regardless of the text that is between undersocre (because that is datetime and random number)
So how could i do it in karatedsl ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
* def foo = { bar: '056722008232004108e1006000000000000001000524__184917547749997761__201905' }
* match foo.bar == '#regex 056722008232004108e1006000000000000001000524__.+'
```

There are plenty of other ways or better regular expressions, read the docs to understand more.